# Unable to get rid of repo on Centos 7

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, repository

I have a Centos 7 machine on which I am trying to install `PHP 5.6` and associated binaries. For this purpose, I installed the `epel` and the `remi` repos. I also installed the `webtatic` repo which now is resulting in some broken dependencies. To resolve them, I removed the `webtatic` repo using:
`sudo yum remove webtatic-release-7-3.noarch`  and `sudo yum clean all`

Both these commands have not yielded results because the dependency resolution is still broken:

```
Error: Package: php56w-mysql-5.6.16-1.w7.x86_64 (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-pdo(x86-64)
           Removing: php56w-pdo-5.6.16-1.w7.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.16-1.w7
           Obsoleted By: php-pdo-5.6.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
Error: Package: php56w-opcache-5.6.16-1.w7.x86_64 (@webtatic)
           Requires: php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.16-1.w7
           Removing: php56w-common-5.6.16-1.w7.x86_64 (@webtatic)
               php56w-common(x86-64) = 5.6.16-1.w7
           Obsoleted By: php-common-5.6.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
```

I have tried:
1. Removing the `webtatic.repo` file from `/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo`
2. Used `rpm -e` and various other variants to remove this repo.
3. Tried to list the repo with `sudo yum repolist all` (this does not show webtatic as a repo).

None of these approaches have worked.
How do I remove the webtatic repo and get rid of this broken dependencies issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the configuration for the repository does not delete the packages you got from it, and *those* are the ones with broken dependencies.

[CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) **warns forcefully** that some third party repositories ***break the system*** by overwriting core packages. There are a few vetted repositories, checked (somewhat) not do cause terrible grief.

Delete the broken packages (`yum delete broken-package`), get rid of the extraofficial repositories (except for [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) they really aren't under any close relation with CentOS proper). Then do a `yum distro-sync` and `package-cleanup --problems` to (hopefully) fix the breakage.

Comment: How do I find and delete the broken packages?

Comment: When I do a `sudo yum list installed | grep -i "brokenpackagename"` or find it in sudo yum search, these return empty results...

Comment: I just did a `sudo yum remove <broken package name>`. That resolved it! Phew!!! Why don't you add that to your answer and I will mark it correct? Thanks for all your help.